# cookies control

Tags: cookies

what tool wold you recommend me to use in order to see what data are stored in my cookies while i'm browsing the net.

I'm a beginner into webdev field(6 months php experience) and i'm curious to see what data are stored into my computer while i'm browsing besides default OS file explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Firefox (if you dont have it yet) and get one of these addons:

Firecookie: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683

Web Developer Toolbar: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60

Answer (score 1):

On Google Chrome, just go "tools" -> "options" -> "under the hood" -> "show cookies"

Answer (score 0):

Every (good) browser lets you to view cookies it stores. In Firefox they sit somewhere in Preferences->Privacy

Answer (score 0):

In Opera, you can either 1) right-click on the current page, choose Edit Site Preferences, and select the Cookies tab, or 2) go to Tools > Advanced > Cookies to see every cookie stored.